# ¿Cómo concatenar dos listas que traigo de una consulta de SQL Server en C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, lista

Traigo dos listas de SQL Server, Cada lista tiene 13 registros, quiero concatenarlos y guardarlos en otra lista, use la función a.Concat(b); pero parece ser que me suma la lista 1 a la lista 2, me trae 26 registros, yo quiero los mismos 13 registros, más o menos de ésta manera.

"Fecha1lista1" + "Fecha1lista2"

"Fecha2lista1" + "Fecha2lista2"

pero el resultado que obtengo es:

"Fecha1Lista1"

"Fecha1Lista2"

"Fecha2Lista1"

"Fecha2Lista2"

Alguna manera de solucionarlo?

```
public List<String> ListaFechas(string llaveEmp)
        {

            List<string> lstFechasI = new List<string>();
            List<string> lstFechasF = new List<string>();
            List<string> lstFechasUnidas = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source = snare.arvixe.com; initial catalog=******; user id=******; password=******"))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    llaveEmp = "158b893b-1579-4086-a03c-e1806adf999a";
                    string query = "SELECT DISTINCT idQuincena, rangoInicial, rangoFinal FROM promCierreVenta WHERE llaveEmp = @llave ORDER BY idQuincena DESC ";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@llave", llaveEmp);

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lstFechasI.Add(reader["rangoInicial"].ToString());
                        lstFechasF.Add(reader["rangoFinal"].ToString());
                    }
                   lstFechasUnidas = lstFechasI.Concat(lstFechasF).ToList();
                }
                return lstFechasUnidas;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return lstFechasUnidas;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Las dos listas las sacas de Sql Server?

Comment: @LuisFernando así es amigo, viene las dos de una consulta sql

Comment: Puedes probar asi: No recuerdo exactamente como es:    Puedes usar Union

`lstFechasUnidas  = lstFechasI.Union(lstFechasF).List();

string[] result = lstFechasI.Union(lstFechasF).List();` Prueba cual de las dos puede funcionar

Comment: @LuisFernando Me sigue trayendo 26 registros, los suma

Comment: Habia entendido mal, lo siento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se trabaja de esa forma, tienes que usar clases

```
public class fechaItem
{
    public string FechasI {get;set;}
    public string FechasF {get;set;}
}
```

y despues usas esto para que cada item de la lista tengan ambos datos

```
public List<fechaItem> ListaFechas(string llaveEmp)
{

    try
    {
        List<fechaItem> lstFechas = new List<fechaItem>();

        string connstring = "data source = snare.arvixe.com; initial catalog=******; user id=******; password=******";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            cn.Open();
            llaveEmp = "158b893b-1579-4086-a03c-e1806adf999a";
            string query = @"SELECT DISTINCT idQuincena, rangoInicial, rangoFinal 
                            FROM promCierreVenta 
                            WHERE llaveEmp = @llave ORDER BY idQuincena DESC ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@llave", llaveEmp);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                fechaItem item = new fechaItem();
                item.FechasI = reader["rangoInicial"].ToString();
                item.FechasF = reader["rangoFinal"].ToString();

                lstFechas.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return lstFechasUnidas;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //aqui logueas el error
        return null;
    }
}
```

como veras en cada loop del reader creas una nueva instancia de la clase para agregarle las dos fechas en sus propiedades, que al final se asigna a la lista

Comment: Mil gracias, funcionó perfecto para mí, y gracias también por el tip de las clases